# How to access sphinx_select in search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using thinking sphinx, with the sphinx_select parameter to create a dynamic field, like so:

```
@subjects = Subject.search(sphinx_select: "*, petals < 1 or color = 2 as my_attribute")
```

Is there any way to access `custom_attribute` in the search results? For example:

```
@subjects.each do |s|
    s.my_attribute
end
```

Returns

```
undefined method `my_attribute' for #<Subject:0x007fb25cdcdb18>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging in the thinking sphinx source and figured this out. The dynamic attributes are stored in a `match` object, which can be accessed like so:

```
@subjects.each_with_match do |s, match|
    match[:attributes]["my_attribute"]
end
```